# Fixing content at the bottom of the screen in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

How do you make buttons and other content stay fixed at the bottom of the screen, regardless to other content?

I have a layout like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <TextView ... />

            ...

            <TextView ... />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ButtonMain"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/button_text"
            android:textSize="30px"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:width="200px" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

And I want the bottom of ButtonMain to always be at the bottom of the screen. However, the button is rendered just below the content in the linearlayout, and not at the bottom of the screen. I've tried `layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"`, as well as placing the button inside its own LinearLayout with similar gravity, but that didn't work.

How can I accomplish this layout?

Comment: Are you trying to render the `Button` at the bottom of the screen statically, despite the `ScrollView`?

Comment: @Eric, Yes, exactly. When I tried placing the button outside the ScrollView, I received numerous errors.

Answer (score 2):

You can use RelativeLayout instead of a LinearLayout. by adding the following tag it will be aliened to the button of the screen

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

if you want the button to be always at the bottom you should put the ScrollView inside the RelativeLayout with the button at its bottom

see:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html

Comment: This just causes all elements to be stretched across the screen.

Comment: you can define padding and margins between the components

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the Scroll view in a relative Layout, but the Buttons in the xml file first with the alignParentBottom field set to true.  Then put the scrollView in and set it to be above the Buttons.  Then the scrollview will fill in the rest of the space and always be above the buttons which will display all the time and not scroll.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Hello2"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom|center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ButtonMain"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:text="click me"
                android:textSize="30px"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my answer, would you please check it and let me know if there is any problem?

Answer (score 1):

As per comments above, the OP wants the `Button` outside his `ScrollView`. However, XML can only have one root element, so you must wrap the `ScrollView` and `Button` in a layout of some kind.

I've demonstrated that below, using your initial layout and dimensions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <!-- You can remove one of these two LinearLayouts, since they just nest each other. Which one you want to remove is up to you. -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView ... />

                ...

                <TextView ... />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="@string/button_text"
        android:textSize="30px"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:width="200px" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Let me know if you have any issues!